# Migrating from prototye to Jquery Rails, empty() functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prototype

I am migrating a rails 3 application from prototype to Jquery, .empty() function is not working on a dhtmlx grid object.

Below is the part of code which is generating error.

```
tree = new dhtmlXTreeObject("treeboxbox_tree","100%","100%",0);
tree.filterState.empty() // Line generating error
```

However when i console.log the values is an proper string and has the value which it is supposed to have.

How do i make it work in Jquery?

Can anyone also direct me to guidelines are points to be covered / implemented when migrating from prototype to Jquery

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below link. It might be helpful. http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2008/09/migrating-to-jquery.html